# Why .value is not getting the value of the input field?

Tags: javascript

I wanted to change the border radius of the div as the input value. can anybody please acknowledge me what is missing here.

HTML

```
<div id="container">
<p class="test">
Test
</p>
<input id="value" type="number" />
<input type="submit" id="submit"/>
</div>
```

JS

```
let btn=document.getElementById('submit');
let value=document.getElementById('value');
let border=document.getElementById("container").style.borderRadius
let pixelVal=value.value+"px";

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
console.log(pixelVal);
    border=value+"px"
})
```

Comment: Because you tried to read it, before the user even had a chance to fill the field. You need to do this _inside_ your button click callback function, if you always want to get the _current_ value of the inout field at that point.

Comment: An unrelated remark: You might want to change the ID of the submit button to something else than `submit`. This will save you a _lot_ of headaches later down the road, when you wonder, where the `form.submit is not a function` errors are coming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to move the pixel calculation and style changing lines inside the click event listener's callback function.

Otherwise both of these code of lines will be executed only once, and that too before the click listener event runs.

But we want that style to be applied every-time we click submit button.

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('submit');
let value = document.getElementById('value');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let pixelVal = value.value + "px";
  console.log(pixelVal);
  document.getElementById("container").style.borderRadius = pixelVal;
})
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <p class="test">
    Test
  </p>

  <input id="value" type="number" />
  <input type="submit" id="submit" />
</div>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this code for orientation.

The input value is read in the click event:

```js
let btn=document.getElementById('submit');
let value=document.getElementById('value');
let container=document.getElementById("container");

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  container.style.borderRadius = value.value + 'px';
})
```

```css
#container {
padding: 10px;
border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<p class="test">
Test
</p>
<input id="value" type="number" />
<input type="submit" id="submit"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `pixelVal` is moved inside the event listener. This ensures that the value of the input is read when the button is clicked and not when the script is initially loaded.
2. Access the style property of the container element in the event listener.

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('submit');
let value = document.getElementById('value');
let border = document.getElementById("container");

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    let pixelVal = value.value+"px";
    console.log(pixelVal);
    border.style.borderRadius = pixelVal;
})
```

```css
#container {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <p class="test"> Test</p>
  <input id="value" type="number" />
  <input type="submit" id="submit"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      #container{
        background-color: yellow;
        border: 1px solid black;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <p class="test">Test</p>
      <input id="value" type="number" />
      <input type="submit" id="submit" />
    </div>
  </body>
  <script>
    let btn = document.getElementById("submit");
    btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
      let value = document.getElementById("value");
      let border = document.getElementById("container");
      let pixelVal = value.value + "px";
      console.log(pixelVal);
      border.style.borderRadius = pixelVal
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

- Here I have improved your code so now its working. Input value should
  be only fetched when button is clicked otherwise It will be null. Thats
  why Your code is not working as you want.
- Let me know if you don't get...Thank You...!